# x86 linux - GAS - AT&T - Stosb?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am currently trying to teach myself x86 under the circumstances posted in my title. Please note I do not just want an answer, I want to learn this and be fluent in it.

I am having a lot of trouble storing data in memory addresses other than the main registers (`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`).

```
.global main

.text

str: .string "data: %d\n"

main:

pushl   $3 
call    malloc
popl    %ecx
movl    $4, %esi          #source 
movl    %eax, %edi       #destination
stosb
movl    %eax, %esi
lodsb
pushl   %edi
pushl   $str
call    printf
popl    %ecx
popl    %ecx
```

After the `stosb`, shouldn't `movl` put the destination address (memory address produced from `malloc`, and original source address) into the destination address, and move the `$4` in `%esi` back into `%edi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stosb` stores a single *byte*. In x86, an address is a dword, so you needed to use `stosd` instead. (Remember that `stosb` and `lodsb` write to/read from `%al`, and `stosd` and `lodsd` write to/read from `%eax`.)

Also, your `$4` was initially stored in `%esi`, but that was later overwritten by the `movl %eax, %esi` instruction.

Comment: I tried this but am getting: add.s:19: Error: no such instruction: `stosd'

Comment: Gah, it's probably called `stosl` in AT&T syntax. (I'm 10x more familiar with Intel syntax since that's what I grew up with.)

Comment: To explain the distinction, a 32-bit quantity is also known as a dword or long. Intel syntax prefers to use `d`; AT&T syntax prefers to use `l`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. However, note that `stosb` does *not* make any use of `esi` (or `ecx`). `rep stosb` will make use of `ecx`: read the descriptions of both forms of that instruction carefully and make sure you are doing the right thing.

You can download Intel's reference manual from [this page.](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)